# Why is my service not returning anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an app using Ionic Framework 7 AngularJS

```
$ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:  
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
OS: Distributor ID: LinuxMint Description:  Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca 
Node Version: v0.12.2
```

The page I'm building retrieve a list of church services and displays them in a master detail list. So I put the $http code in a Service as per the following code:

**services.js :**

```
.service('ServicesService', ['$http', '$sce', function($http, $sce){

var services = [];

$http.get('http://demo0194057.mockable.io/services').then(function(response) {
        services = response.data;
        window.q = services; //checking value of services var

}, function(error) {
    console.error("Error loading Services Endpoint! " + error);
});

return {
    getAllServices: function() {
        console.log('from inside return obj ' + services);
        window.p = services; // checking value of services var
           return services;
    }

}

}])
```

**controller.js :**

```
.controller('servicesCtrl', function($scope, $http, ServicesService, InfoService) {
$scope.services = [];

$scope.services = ServicesService.getAllServices();
window.r = $scope.services;

 $scope.doRefresh = function() {
                $http.get('http://demo0194057.mockable.io/services').success(function(response) {
                $scope.services = response;
            })
            .finally(function() {
                // stop the ion-refresher from spinning
                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
            });
            }


})
```

So my problem is that the service is returning an empty array instead of an array of objects from the JSON REST API. I put some debugging variables in the code and I can see that from the controller, the service is returning an empty array (var window.r). From within the service, window.p is also empty, however window.q has the correct object data which means that the API call is working fine. I can't figure out where that data is getting lost though, such that it's not being successfully returned from the service.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this:

**Service**

```
.service('ServicesService', ['$http', '$sce', function($http, $sce){
    var services = [];

    return {
        getAllServices: function() {
            return $http.get('http://demo0194057.mockable.io/services').then(function(response) {
                    services = response.data;
                    return services;
            }, function(error) {
                console.error("Error loading Services Endpoint! " + error);
            });
        }

    }
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('servicesCtrl', function($scope, $http, ServicesService, InfoService) {
    $scope.services = [];
    $scope.doRefresh = function() {
        ServicesService.getAllServices().then(function (response) {
            $scope.services = response;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your service you need to do the `$http.get` request inside the body of `getAllServices` method. Otherwise, the get request's then clause gets executed after the call to `getAllServices` is made by the controller which is why the `services` variable isn't initialized at that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get('http://demo0194057.mockable.io/services').then(function(response) {
        services = response.data;
        window.q = services; //checking value of services var

}, function(error) {
    console.error("Error loading Services Endpoint! " + error);
});
```

This is async function. So services = response.data will be executed somtimes later.

$scope.services = ServicesService.getAllServices(); This will be call just after angular will rise and probably **before**  your async get wil be executed.

So. If you wont to get your services you have to wrap your ServicesService.getAllServices(); as a promise where you will wait your first request. But it seems there are some architecture problems... Try to push your code away for a while and redisign it.